# Unable to change cursor image in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cursor, multiple-browsers

```
  <body class="gamerboard1">
  </body>

.gamerboard1
{
cursor:url(../assets/curser.png), url(../assets/curser.cur),auto;   

}
```

Hi All,

I have to change the cursor image for all browsers.Cursor image changes well in Chrome and Firefox but fails to do in IE browsers. I have included the .cur file for IE but its not working for IE. 
Please Help . 
           I have provided the DOCTYPE too

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
cursor: url('../assets/curser.png'), default;
```

Comment: cursor: url('../assets/curser.png'), default; its working only for chrome not for IE

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cursor is plain buggy in IE, at least until and including 10

In Internet Explorer for Windows up to and including version 10, if a relative URI value is specified in an external style sheet file the base URI is considered to be the URI of the document containing the element and not the URI of the style sheet in which the declaration appears.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

You may want be able to use a conditional comment to target IE and then feed it a modified style rule with a different url.

Comment: The size of my cursor image is 31px x 37px.. will this play a major issue for IE ?

Comment: Should not, check this in IE http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url%28smiley.gif%29,url%28myBall.cur%29,auto